# automate letsencrypt on a kubernetes app with lots of domains

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, caddy

I have a node app that loads its data based on domain name. domains are configured with a CNAME like `app.service.com` (which is the node app).

The Node app sees the request domain and sends a request to API to get app data.

for example: `domain.com` CNAME `app.service.com`
-> then node app asks api for domain.com data

the problem is setting up HTTPS (with letsencrypt) for all the domains. I think cert-manager can help but have no idea how to automate this without the need to manually change config file for each new domain.

or is there a better way to achieve this in Kubernetes?

Comment: in your case does wild card certificate work or not ?

Comment: Look at cert-manager (https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager).

Comment: @HarshManvar: no since the domains are different. for example: domain1.com and domain2.com both point to the same k8s app.

Comment: @johnharris85: I just don't know how to automate that using cert-manager. I know how that works with config and manually adding domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard method to support more than one domain name and / or subdomain names is to use one SSL Certificate and implement SAN (Subject Alternative Names). The extra domain names are stored together in the SAN. All SSL certificates support SAN, but not all certificate authorities will issue multi-domain certificates. Let's Encrypt does support [SAN](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-san-certificate/) so their certificates will meet your goal.

First, you have to create a [job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) in our cluster that uses an image to run a shell script. The script will spin up an HTTP service, create the certs, and save them into a predefined secret. Your domain and email are environment variables, so be sure to fill those in:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-job
  labels:
    app: letsencrypt
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: letsencrypt
      labels:
        app: letsencrypt
    spec:
      containers:
      # Bash script that starts an http server and launches certbot
      # Fork of github.com/sjenning/kube-nginx-letsencrypt
      - image: quay.io/hiphipjorge/kube-nginx-letsencrypt:latest
        name: letsencrypt
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: letsencrypt
          containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: DOMAINS
          value: kubernetes-letsencrypt.jorge.fail # Domain you want to use. CHANGE ME!
        - name: EMAIL
          value: jorge@runnable.com # Your email. CHANGE ME!
        - name: SECRET
          value: letsencrypt-certs
      restartPolicy: Never
```

You have a job running, so you can create a service to direct traffic to this job:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  selector:
    app: letsencrypt
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
```

This job will now be able to run, but you still have three things we need to do before our job actually succeeds and we’re able to access our service over HTTPs.

First, you need to create a secret for the job to actually update and store our certs. Since you don’t have any certs when we create the secret, the secret will just start empty.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-certs
type: Opaque

# Create an empty secret (with no data) in order for the update to work
```

Second, you’ll have to add the secret to the Ingress controller in order for it to fetch the certs. Remember that it is the Ingress controller that knows about our host, which is why our certs need to be specified here. The addition of our secret to the Ingress controller will look something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "kubernetes-demo-app-ingress-service"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - kubernetes-letsencrypt.jorge.fail # Your host. CHANGE ME
    secretName: letsencrypt-certs # Name of the secret
  rules:
```

Finally you have to redirect traffic through the host, down to the job, through our Nginx deployment. In order to do that you’ll add a new route and an upstream to our Nginx configuration: This could be done through the Ingress controller by adding a `/.well-known/*` entry and redirecting it to the letsencrypt service. That’s more complex because you would also have to add a health route to the job, so instead you’ll just redirect traffic through the Nginx deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  default.conf: |
```

...

```
    # Add upstream for letsencrypt job
    upstream letsencrypt {
      server letsencrypt:80 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=1s;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
```

...

```
      # Redirect all traffic in /.well-known/ to letsencrypt
      location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        proxy_pass http://letsencrypt;
      }
    }
```

After you apply all these changes, destroy your Nginx Pod(s) in order to make sure that the ConfigMap gets updated correctly in the new Pods:

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep ngi | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pods
```

Make sure it works.

In order to verify that this works, you should make sure the job actually succeeded. You can do this by getting the job through kubectl, you can also check the Kubernetes dashboard.

```
$ kubectl get job letsencrypt-job
NAME              DESIRED   SUCCESSFUL   AGE
letsencrypt-job   1         1            1d
```

You can also check the secret to make sure the certs have been properly populated. You can do this through kubectl or through the dashboard:

```
$ kubectl describe secret letsencrypt-certs

Name:   letsencrypt-certs
Namespace:  default
Labels:   <none>
Annotations:
Type:   Opaque
Data
====
tls.crt:  3493 bytes
tls.key:  1704 bytes
```

Now that as you can see that the certs have been successfully created, you can do the very last step in this whole process. For the Ingress controller to pick up the change in the secret (from having no data to having the certs), you need to update it so it gets reloaded. In order to do that, we’ll just add a timestamp as a label to the Ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "kubernetes-demo-app-ingress-service"
  labels:
    # Timestamp used in order to force reload of the secret
    last_updated: "1494099933"
...
```

Please take a look at: [kubernetes-letsencrypt](https://runnable.com/blog/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-on-kubernetes).

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, really appreciate it. it's almost perfectly what I needed. Can I just do all those kubectl stuff with API? This will allow me to integrate this into my app so it won't be manual job

Comment: Doesn't work for me anymore. My pods are failing because of an outdated ACME client. ```The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430 for details.``` I mean, the image is also about 4 years old

Comment: This no longer works as ACMEv1 has been deprecated. See: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/end-of-life-plan-for-acmev1/88430